# What are some good resources for debugging/disassembling proprietary software?

Tags: debugging, third-party-libraries, reverse-engineering

From time to time, I experience different bugs with proprietary software that I need to interact with. In order to get through these bugs, I need to develop various workarounds. Is there a good book for debugging/disassembling proprietary software to write better workarounds?

Comment: Most of the tools and techniques used in debugging and disassembling are operating systems and/or language specific. Are you looking for a general OS/language agnostic book? Or a book specifically on some OS+language combination?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a general OS/language agnostic book. But I will appreciate any suggestion for specific one.

Comment: Dissambling or otherwise reverse engineering is in violation of the EULA's of most proprietary programs.  That may or may not be legally enforceable or morally sound, but at very least, you can expect a very chilly response from the vendors who's software you are reverse engineering.

Comment: It is legal to disassemble purchased software in Russia. At least not illegal.

Comment: Note that you essentially want to reverse the compiler used.  Depending on how good it is you may have to analyze machine code without debug symbols to understand what goes on.  This is not a trivial task and is hard to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Windows Debugging

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321374460/ref=oss_product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321374460)

Advanced .NET Debugging

[http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-NET-Debugging-Mario-Hewardt/dp/0321578899/ref=pd_sim_b_2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321578899)

Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering

[http://www.amazon.com/Reversing-Secrets-Engineering-Eldad-Eilam/dp/0764574817/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1296931123&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764574817)

The IDA Pro Book: The Unofficial Guide to the World's Most Popular Disassembler

[http://www.amazon.com/IDA-Pro-Book-Unofficial-Disassembler/dp/1593271786/ref=pd_sim_b_3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271786)

Introduction to 80x86 Assembly Language and Computer Architecture

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Assembly-Language-Computer-Architecture/dp/0763772232/ref=pd_sim_b_12](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0763772232)